# Why do I have to use L prefix in Windows but can't use (SQLWCHAR *) and vice-versa on unix

Tags: c, windows, odbc, unixodbc

I am working with ODBC to connect to MySQL database. I am working on windows but I want my code to run on linux as well. I have problem with database connection and passing strings in general.

ODBC functions expects me to send (SQLWCHAR *) - note the W. If I cast a string this way in Windows, I'll get odbc error (dsn not found or username invalid)

```
(SQLWCHAR *)"MyUsername"
```

However this one will work

```
L"MyUsername"
```

On the other hand on linux it's exactly opposite. `L` prefix won't work but `SQLWCHAR *` cast will.

The second problem (related) is when printing out results. On windows I have to use

```
printf("%ls");
```

when on linux I have to use

```
prinf("%s");
```

Is there any way to unify it?

Comment: `"MyUsername"` is a string of `char`s. The fact that you are casting it to a pointer-to-wide-char only results in undefined behavior; it won't magically convert the underlying data to an array of wide chars. A true array of wide chars is `L"MyUsername"`.

Comment: Then why does `L"MyUsername"` doesn't work on Unix then if it's the proper way to do so.

Comment: It's possible that `SQLWCHAR` is even wider (e. g. 4 bytes) than `wchar_t` (e. g. 2 bytes) on your platform.

Comment: Whatever library you use (don't keep it a secret) appears to have typedef-ed SQLWCHAR to a narrow string type instead of `wchar_t`.  That's pretty unfortunate, but not uncommon, wchar_t isn't very popular on Linux.  But yes, portability out of the window.

Comment: Ain't secret at all :) On linux it's unixODBC, on Windows.. well I guess Windows inbuilt odbc (it came with the system). SQLWCHAR on windows maps to wchar_t indeed, however it's on linux that SQLWCHAR works, not on windows